# How to disable alpha of application menu?

Tags: xfce

I have gentoo and xfce 4.12.
My application menu, when i hover it: http://mpc.iso.vc/screenshot.png
What i need do, to disable alpha on it?

Comment: Doesn't seem to apply to the menu, but `alt+scroll` over a window decoration (top bar) allows to manage the window transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the opacity of popup windows.

The following instructions are applicable to Xfce 4.8 and newer.

1. Open **Settings Manager** or run `xfce4-settings-manager`
2. Go to **Window Manager Tweaks - Compositor**
3. Look for the option **Opacity of popup windows:** (toward last entry)
4. Drag the slider control until the furthest right (toward *Opaque*)
5. Finally, click **Close**

Now the popup menu is no longer transparent and fully opaque.

**Before**: Semi-transparent

[image: Xfce4 menu is semi-transparent]

**After**: Fully opaque

[image: Xfce4 menu is fully opaque]